# Multiboot-Ubuntu with Encryption (UEFI)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 18.04, uefi, encryption

I want to install three Ubuntus on one system with encryption on UEFI. How should my partition table look?

This is now my partition table:

[image: My current partition table] 
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

I want to edit this to a UEFI multiboot with encryption

Comment: Typically, an installation consists of boot, root, home, swap (swap if pre-18.04 release). For boot encryption read this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ManualFullSystemEncryption